# getline and fgets failed to get input on first attempt

Tags: c

```
void someFunction(){
    char *buffer;
    size_t bufsize = 32;
    int bytes_read;

    for (;;) {
        buffer = (char *) malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));
        if (buffer == NULL) {
            perror("Unable to allocate buffer");
            exit(1);
        }

        FILE *ptr;
        ptr = fopen("sample.txt", "a");
        printf("Enter Stuff to write down:\n");
        //getline(&buffer,&bufsize,stdin);
        //fgets(buffer, 30, stdin);
        //scanf("%[^\n]%*c", buffer);
        //scanf("%s", buffer);

        if (buffer[0] == '0') {
            break;
        }

        WriteWithFprintf(ptr, buffer);
        free(buffer);
        fclose(ptr);
    }
}
```

The problem is: if I use

```
    getline(&buffer,&bufsize,stdin);
```

or

```
    fgets(buffer, 30, stdin);
```

then it escapes the first like so:

```
    Enter Stuff to write down:
    Enter Stuff to write down:
    0
```

If I use:

```
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", buffer);
```

then I get an infinite loop.

It does work with:

```
   scanf("%s", buffer);
```

but I want input with space so this is not an option for me.

Comment: Aside: instead of this nasty (and ineffective) kludge `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", buffer);` use `scanf(" %[^\n]", buffer);` Notice the added space.

Comment: Those two are not equivalent, @WeatherVane.

Comment: Using `getline` or `fgets` you will never reach the `break` as both include the `\n` character.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I know. But because of the lack of a space at the beginning, that kludge would need to be applied to all `scanf` lines, no matter what the specifiers. The `scanf` is designed to filter whitespace, when used correctly.

Comment: Do you use `scanf` somewhere before you call that function? Please show a minimal complete program that reproduces the issue. A common issue when mixing `scanf` and `fgets` is [scanf() leaves the newline character in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-newline-character-in-the-buffer)

Comment: Anuj Borah, prior unposted code used `scanf()` in such a way the a `'\n'` was left in `stdin`.

Comment: @WeatherVane, your suggestion will consume not just one leading newline, but any amount of leading whitespace.  It appears that that would not be a problem for the specific input the OP has / expects, but it should not go unremarked.  Unlike the OP's variation, yours will also leave a trailing newline unread if there is one.  That should not go unremarked either.

Comment: @JohnBollinger the other format specifiers also leave a newline in the buffer. By removing it here, the OP has added yet another difference of the behaviour of `%[]` from other specifiers. They all leave unprocessed input in the buffer. I still say, it's an ill-advised solution.

Comment: @WeatherVane, the OP's `"%[^\n]%*c"` *does not* leave a trailing newline in the buffer, provided that the `%[` matches anything and there are not two trailing newlines in a row.  That is presumably the intent of the `%*c`, and certainly is its effect.

Comment: @JohnBollinger obvoiusly that is the point, but you have a few *provideds* in there. I am saying *every* format specifier leaves the unprocessed input in the buffer (which might not be wanted), so why should you make an exception here? As mentioned, if you are not going to use a leading space with `%c` and `%[]` then this kludge is needed everywhere else too. IMO its a terrible solution to remove trailing whitespace like this. A kludge.

Comment: @WeatherVane, the point is that you have suggested an alternative that has different behavior in this regard, without saying anything about the difference.  And inasmuch as the OP is raising the `scanf` as an alternative to `getline()` and `fgets()`, it is sensible to choose a variation that indeed does consume a trailing newline.

Comment: @Anuj Borah. What user input do you expect leads to `buffer[0] == '0'` to be true?

Comment: @WeatherVane Suggesting `scanf(" %[^\n]", buffer);`, without a _width_ is like suggesting evil `gets()`.  Rather than solve one problem and pose another, better fix both:  `scanf(" %31[^\n]", buffer);`.

Comment: @WeatherVane works as charm  thanks

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica canf(" %31[^\n]", buffer); too work as charm thansk

Answer (score 1):

All of the behaviors described for different variations on your code are consistent with the next character available to be read from `stdin` being a newline, presumably from a preceding line of input.

In that case,

- the `getline()` and `fgets()` alternatives will read the newline (and any preceding characters) as a line, and then loop to read the line you actually want on the second pass.
- the first `scanf()` variation will read *nothing* on account of a matching failure for the `%[^\n]` field (leading whitespace is not skipped for `%[` directives).  Not having matched anything to that, there will be no attempt to match anything to the `%*c`.
- the second `scanf()` alternative will work as you describe, because `scanf` will automatically consume leading whitespace when processing a `%s` directive, including any newline.

There is a variety of things you could do, depending on exactly how want to handle input.  Here is one:

```
    int c = fgetc(stdin);
    if (c == EOF) {
        // handle eof ...
    } else if (c != '\n') {
        ungetc(c, stdin);
    }
    // your choice for reading the wanted data ...
```

That will consume up to one leading newline from `stdin` to get it out of your way.

Comment: Well yes, @chux, *in that case* `scanf` will consume leading whitespace.  The previous point establishes that `scanf` does not *always* do so.  But I have edited to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

> getline and fgets failed to get input on first attempt

Neither failed.  Both simply read a `'\n'` and immediately returned.  This `'\n'` was left-over from a previous input function like `scanf("%s", ...)`, that did not consume the entire *line*.  `getline()` is not part of the standard C library.

`scanf("%[^\n]%*c", buffer);` fails to read anything when the first available character is `'\n'`.

`scanf("%s", buffer);` consumes all optional leading white space like `'\n'`.  This may appear to work for OP.

`scanf("%[^\n]%*c", buffer);` and `scanf("%s", buffer);` are both poor code as they do not have a *width* limit, risking buffer overflow.

---

I recommend for a learner to not use `scanf()` at all and perform *all* input with `fgets()`, including the part of code not posted.